# Using DirectoryIterator to loop through a D: drive directory

Tags: php, loops, permissions, directory

I am trying to loop through this directory:

```
$path = "D:\\import\\statsummary\\";
```

Here is my code:

```
$path = "D:\\import\\statsummary\\";
//$path = "C:\\test";
//function load_csv($path, $filename){
    if(is_null($filename)){
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        $output = array();
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file){
            if($file->isFile()){
                $output[] = $i++ . " " . $file->getFileName() . "\n";
                $output[] = file($file->getPathName());
                $output[] = "\n------------\n";
            }
        }
    }

    echo implode('', $output);
```

When I run this script, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(D:\import\statsummary\,D:\import\statsummary\): Access is denied. (code: 5)' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\include\file_importer.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\include\file_importer.php(10): DirectoryIterator->__construct('D:\import\...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\include\file_importer.php on line 10
```

But when I change it to a test directory on my `C:\` drive, it runs just fine. I've even created a username to run PHP as directed in this post:

[php - Unable to connect to network share - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884857/unable-to-connect-to-network-share)

Comment: Did you try it without the trailing slash?

Comment: Yes I have. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [DirectoryIterator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), something like this should work:

```
<?php
$path = "D:/import/statsummary";
$output=array();
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator(path);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $filename= $fileinfo->getFilename();
        $path=$fileinfo->getPathname();
        $output[][$filename]=$path;
    }
}

print_r($output);
?>
```

**Update**

Since you're getting access denied, you'll need to run the `command prompt` (CMD) window as *Administrator* more than likely. If this is on a `link` (lnk) you can change the permissions in the link settings.

For instance if you right-click on the shortcut for cmd as select `properties`, you would go to shortcut>advanced>Run as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your response AbsoluteZERO, but I am still getting the same `Access Denied` error.

Comment: I'm getting "The sytem cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)"

Comment: Start another question. Or put in the correct path.