# unable to move files to network share folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload files into the shared folder, I have permission to read/write inside that folder (i can create a folder inside my shared folder). but when I submit the form I am always getting these warnings. I am using xampp local server

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(\17.105.103.8\History\TQ_Books\1.PDF):
> failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bookshelfs\app\controllers\Books.php on line 144
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php10D7.tmp' to '\17.105.103.8\History\TQ_Books\1.PDF' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookshelfs\app\controllers\Books.php on line 144

This is my code

```
$bookExt = pathinfo($_FILES['select_book']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = ltrim($_POST['book_no'], '0') . '.' . $bookExt;
$tmpFilename = $_FILES['select_book']['tmp_name'];
$targetDir = '\\\\17.105.103.8\\History\\TQ_Books\\';
$fileTarget = $targetDir . $filename;

if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilename, $fileTarget)) {
     die("success, uploaded");
} else {
     die("not uploaded");
}
```

**UPDATE**
I checked file path by file_exists method it gives not exists and also checked with is_writeable method it gives false too

Comment: I think that in order to move file to remote directory you should try some sort of FTP access (or FTP function)

Comment: really i have no idea about what you are saying mate, please help me with it

Comment: @PavelJanicek my folder local share folder connected through LAN, still i need ftp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884857/unable-to-connect-to-network-share)

Comment: You need to make sure the account PHP is running under has access to this network share. (The duplicate explains it for when using IIS, but with a different server/setup it is likely still the same underlying issue.)

Comment: @CBroe I am using xampp local server, the network part really confusing me, please help me with this if there is solution

Answer (score 0):

Give a try by remmoving '\\', try to replace below line with your code

```
$targetDir = '\\\\17.105.103.8\\Qatar_History\\TQ_Books\\';
```

Replace with below

```
$targetDir = '\\17.105.103.8\Qatar_History\TQ_Books\';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a network drive, you need to confirm if you have mapped the drive properly before executing the code. The code should work fine when you have mapped the remote path to a local drive. With the usage of the code, I believe you are on a Windows network. Also please check the usage of \ in $targetDir. The usual format to connect to a network path is \Network IP\shared folder name\

Comment: no, It was not mapped the shared folder, after saw your answer I did mapped it to drive X, now how to give the path?

Comment: This might be of some help to you: https://awesometoast.com/php-and-mapped-network-drives/